# unable to understand how this regex operates on the input string?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex pattern that I am splitting the String on. I don't understand how this is matched and the split happens. I do have basic understanding of regex and how it works.

```
public class URLmatching {

    private static final Pattern SPLIT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])");


    public void print() throws URISyntaxException{

        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        final String[] string = SPLIT_PATTERN.split(getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException{

URLmatching u = new URLmatching();
        u.print();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
URLmatching
[UR, Lmatching]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression uses both negative look-behind (`?<!`), and positive look-ahead (`?=`).

Negative look-behind checks if the expression inside the paranthesis matches immediately before the current posistion. So, in the first example `(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))` it checks that the previous position was not beginning of string or any of `[A-Z0-9]`.

Look-ahead checks if the expression matches immediately after the current position.

So, this expression will split if one of the two conditions matches:

1. `(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))(?=[A-Z])` - This will match if the previous character is not beginning of string (`^`) or `A-Z0-9` and the next one is `A-Z`. In other words, it won't match anywhere here.
   An example where it would match would be `UrlMatching`, where it would match between `l` and `M`.
2. `(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])` - This matches if the previous character is not beginning of string, and the next two characters are an upper-case letter (`A-Z`) followed by a lower-case letter (`a-z`). This only matches in one place, immediately before the upper-case `L`, giving you the output you observe.

Comment: can you please give an example of a case where 1 matches. And please explain what `(?<!` in 1 supposed to do.

Comment: Again for 2) can you please explain what this does `(?<!^)`. If you can provide a step by step break down of how 2 i.e `(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])`, it will be very very helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have expanded the answer a bit, hopefully it answers all your questions now.

Comment: I tried this `(?<![ABC])` on these two strings: ABC and abc and both show match. I don't understand how..

Comment: so is `?<` or `?<!`  negative look behind. I assume it is the latter. why is there a match at end in first case and why NOT a match in beginning for second case?

Comment: `?<!` is negative look-behind. You can read more and see a few examples in [this excellent tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).